# Custom Qt designer widget : a scroll Area containing a custom vertical layout

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qt-designer

I want to do something fairly simple : add a custom widget to Qt designer that would basically be a scrollArea containing a custom vertical layout(I added some code to the vertical layout in order to handle its objects for my projects). 
The idea would be to represent a vertical menu that would be on the side of my screen

**What I have done so far**

I created the custom widget plugin and my custom layout.

My custom widget codes looks like this:

```
#include "menuwidget.h"

MenuWidget::MenuWidget(QWidget *parent) :
        QScrollArea(parent)
{
    this->setWidgetResizable(true);
    QWidget* layoutHoldingWidget= new QWidget(this);
    layout= new MenuLayout();
    layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);
    layout->addStretch(1);
    layoutHoldingWidget->setLayout(layout);
    this->setWidget(layoutHoldingWidget);
}
```

If I add manually to the layout (in the constructor code) some buttons

```
for(int i =0;i<20;i++)
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton(this));
```

It does work and I can see my scrollArea containing some buttons, which is almost what I want.

**What I want**

I would like to be able to add these buttons directly via Qt designer: the user would first drag the empty MenuWidget on the main window, then would drag QPushButtons on my custom widget exactly like he would do on a regular vertical layout.

Is that possible?How could I do such a thing?

Thank you ! :)

**Edit 1**

What I was missing was the "scrollAreaWidgetContents" widget that is always created when you drag and drop a QScrollArea. I did a similar thing by adding a widget (let's call it containerWidget) to my custom scrollArea in its domXml function, which enables me to drag and drop widgets on my scroll Area like I wanted to do.

BUT there's still something I can't figure out : I want the containerWidget to have a customLayout (myCustomLayout) . If I add it in the domXml function, I get the following line in the terminal :

> Designer:The layout type 'MyCustomLayout' is not supported,
>   defaulting to grid.

So it means that I can't tell designer to use my custom layout to place my widgets, which is kind of sad :D

Is there any way to "cheat" here?

Comment: Read about Custom Widgets in QtDesigner http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: I've read about this and I don't see how it could help me. My question is pretty specific, I think.

Comment: The given link and documentation linked there explain how to extend qt designer with own widget and widget plugins

Comment: Thanks, but I have read this doc countless times. I need some some help about this specific problem...

Comment: I use the given option for subclassed widget and use http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html or http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtdesigner.html guide for creating plugins for QtDesigner. All steps should be mentioned in there. From your description you did not yet create a complete plugin but just a replacement. Your next step would be to reimplement the given virutal functions mentioned in the guide. As far as i can tell almost everything is covered in there, so eventually read those links another time.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I created the QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
 plugin for my widget. I can see it in Qt Designer and drag it. I would need some guidance about the next steps to follow in order to achieve what I would like to do. The answer is very likely to be found in the docs that I have read, but I'm kind of stuck here with my problem. That's why I came to stackoverflow... So my question is :  How can I manage the widgets that I drag and drop in my custom widgets with Qt Designer?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. If your widget does handle everything correctly within code, it should also work within the qtdesigner given the required virtual methods are implemented. Does your widget arrange the child wiget at all? Maybe your drag and droped widgets do not get placed on the layout only on the widget?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question now. I was missing the container widget of the scroll Area. But I can't find a way to apply a custom layout to this container widget yet :/

Comment: Eventually you will need to create a plugin for your customlayout also. Never used this though.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't seem to be supported in Qt 4... http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6322
Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: +1: Interesting question. Finally I found time to test Designed plugin interface :-) I think, the missing point was, layouting mustn't be handled in QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface but in your widget using QObject::childEvent - which is also called when the Widget is edited in QtDesigner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qt 4 does not support custom layout plugins for designer](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6322), so I couldn't achieve what I wanted to do. I will instead use a Vertical Layout and try to implement the additional features that were supposed to be in the custom layout code in the widget code.

Comment: Oh, I was 12 minutes too late :-(

Comment: +1: Thanks for the link! However one could solve this also in the way I suggested. Why should it be a layout after all? Qt Designer creates a fully operational, the same Widget (unless specified otherwise in createWidget), which behaves the same as he widget at run-time. This widget can of cause manage it's content as you specify layout children, create new children itself, move around Qt Designer's GUI, etc.). I guess, the developer in qt-project forum was too focused to customize QLayout, not to solve her problem. (No one needs a borer but a hole)

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to consider:

1) Overwrite in the class you derive from QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface the function to return **true**

```
bool isContainer() const { return true; }
```

This tells QtDesigner that the widget can contain children. (In Qt nearly any Widget can contain any widget as child, but QtDesigner tries to restrict it in a sensible way - e.g. you cant add children to a QLabel in QtDesigner)

2) Implement childEvent of your Widget. Probably in your case it would add Widgets added in QtDesigner to a layout.

Here is a core I've implemented to try this out. I've created a skeleton using "Qt Widget Plugin" Wizard in QtCreator and modified a little bit.

Don't forget to build as **release**, for the compiler/Qt-version of your QtDesigner , to copy the .dll and .lib files in \plugins\designer directory and to **restart** QtDesigner!

***verticalplugin.cpp***

```
//all other functions remained as created by QtCreator wizard
bool VerticalMenuPlugin::isContainer() const
{
    return true;
}
```

***VerticalMenu.h***

```
#ifndef VERTICALMENU_H
#define VERTICALMENU_H

#include <QtGui/QWidget>
#include <QtGui/QVBoxLayout>

class VerticalMenu : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    virtual void childEvent ( QChildEvent * event );
public:
    VerticalMenu(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif
```

***VerticalMenu.cpp***

```
#include "verticalmenu.h"
#include <QChildEvent>

VerticalMenu::VerticalMenu(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setLayout (new QVBoxLayout);
}

void VerticalMenu::childEvent ( QChildEvent * event )
{
    if ( event->added() )
    {
        QWidget * newChild = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(event->child());
        if ( newChild )
        {
            layout()->addWidget( newChild );
        }
    }
}
```

I hope' it would help as a starting point.